# Angular post request got sent twice when return 404

Tags: angular, http, web, http-post, ionic4

I am sending a post request using Angular with Promise.
When the post request returns 200, Everything is awesome.
The issue is when the request returns 404, The API got sent another time.

This is the code I am using:

```
async checkCrValidation() {
    this.loaderService.present(
        await this.helperMethod.translateKeys('i18n.general.savingdata')
    );
    this.userSerivce
        .sendCrValidation(this.authorized_body)
        .then(async (data) => {
            this.toasterService.successToast(
                await this.helperMethod.translateKeys(
                    'i18n.general.success-CrNumber'
                )
            );
            this.loaderService.dismiss();
            this.dismiss(true);
        })
        .catch(async (err) => {
            this.loaderService.dismiss();
            this.toasterService.errorToast(err.error.error.message);
            return throwError(err);
        });
}



sendCrValidation(body): Promise<Request> {
   return this.rest.post('user/cr-validation', body).toPromise();
}




public post(
        relativeUrl: string,
        body: any,
        restOptions: RestOptions = this.initRestOptions
    ): Observable<any> {
        const options = {
            headers: this.getHeaders(restOptions.customHeaders),
        };

        if (restOptions.withHeaders) {
            options['observe'] = 'response';
        }

        return this.http
            .post(`${environment.baseURL}${relativeUrl}`, body, options)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not seeing anything that would cause it here. Whats in your `catchError` function? It could also be something related to how `checkCrValidation` is called in the first place